# Who can access public repos under an Organization in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-organizations

I have a repo under GitHub account of my organization. I found there are two options available about the visibility of the repo **private** and **public**. 
Is **public** repo only visible to all people in my organization or all people on GitHub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A public repository is visible to the public internet.

See [github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/)

> You can choose to make the repository either public or private. Public repositories are visible to the public, while private repositories are only accessible to you, and people you share them with.

There is no difference in the definition of 'public' between organisation and user accounts.

Answer (score -1):

Public repositories are open for everyone in and out of organization.

See: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/ for more details.

> You can choose to make the repository either public or private. Public
>   repositories are visible to the public, while private repositories are
>   only accessible to you, and people you share them with. Your account
>   must be on a paid plan to create a private repository. For more
>   information, see "GitHub's billing plans."

Comment: And this improves on the other existing answer how?

Comment: A paid GitHub account is no longer needed to create a private repository.